# Where's offline storage cache directory of Firefox?

Tags: firefox, directory

I am using Firefox 3.6 as my browser, it's installed on "`C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox`".

But I cannot find offline storage cache directory in it, and I cannot find configuration about cache directory in Firefox either. Anyone knows the directory? Thanks!

Comment: it'll be in your user only data, this depends on operating system (and in the case of windows, version too).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type "about:cache" in the address bar.

It depends on your Windows version. See: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/firefox-cache-files-and-folder-in-windows/ .

Answer (score 0):

The location of Firefox's cache varies depending on your version of Windows, but it's always found in your local user's application data folder.

On Windows XP/2000:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\[Your User Name]\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\
```

On Windows Vista/7:

```
C:\Users\[Your User Name]\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\
```